# Finding the limit of this rational function without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus

I'm having difficulty with this limit. I'll be glad if someone could help me

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {- x} {\sqrt{2}}} $$

Thanks.

Comment: Please share with us the own efforts to solve the exercise, and where is the point where computations got stuck...

Comment: Rationalize the numerator and denominator.

Comment: i have tried first to rationalize the denominator but the numerator still getting 0, and when i tried to rationalize both numerator and denominator i get in nowhere. I also tried to substitute x with secˆ2 but also get 0. I really out of more ideas to do :/

Comment: ** x with tangent **

Comment: When providing new information, please click on the tiny `edit` to improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rationalize numerator and denominator  $ \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{(\sqrt{x+3}-2)}{(\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {- x} {\sqrt{2}})}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x+3-4)(\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {+ x} {\sqrt{2}})}{(1-x^2)(\sqrt{x+3}+2)}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{(\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {+ x} {\sqrt{2}})}{-(x+1)(\sqrt{x+3}+2)}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {- x} {\sqrt{2}}}\\
=&\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x+3-2^2}{\sqrt{x+3}+2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 }+x \sqrt{2}}{x^2+1-2x^2}\\
=&\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2\sqrt2}4\cdot\frac{x-1}{1-x^2}\\
=&\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2\sqrt2}4\cdot\frac{-1}{x+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sqrt{x+3}-2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 } {- x} {\sqrt{2}}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{\dfrac{x-1}{\sqrt{x+3}+2}}{\dfrac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 }+ x {\sqrt{2}}}}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1 }+ x {\sqrt{2}}}{-(1+x)(\sqrt{x+3}+2)}=\cdots$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I find the answer by trying again to rationalize the numerator and denominator.

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x+3}{-2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x\sqrt{2}}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} -\frac{(x-1)(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} {+ x\sqrt{2}})}  {(x+1)(x-1)(\sqrt{x+3}{+2})}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} -\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} {+ x\sqrt{2}}}  {(x+1)(\sqrt{x+3}{+2})}$$

$$= -\frac{\sqrt{2} {+ \sqrt{2}}}  {2(\sqrt{4}{+2})} = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$